# Use an imploded array to build a get statement for a link?

Tags: php

I'm using an array to build a get statement within a while loop. Here is the code I'm using to build the array

//Create an Array for a Mass Update

```
$i++;   
$where=array();
$where[] =$cards['id'].'&';
$query.=  ' id_'.$i.'='.implode($where);
```

When I echo $query, (which is the constructed get statement)I DO get the result I want which is
id_1=1& id_2=2& id_3=3 etc ...

However, when I try to use the $query variable in an echoed link such as this:

```
echo  "<a href=mass_qty_update.php?".rtrim($query,'&')."><button>"."Update All Quantities"."</button></a>";
```

The $query variable returns blank. So in this scenario for my link I'm currently getting:

```
mass_qty_update.php?
```

When I should be getting:

```
mass_qty_update.php?id_1=1& id_2=2& id_3=3
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here. Any help as always is highly appreciated.

Jack

Comment: Try url-encode the string `$query = urlencode($query);`  or you know, just remove the spaces.

Comment: Could you share a bit more of your code? Like, start with the whole loop.

Comment: It's most likely a scope issue though; the place where you echo the value is not the same as where you're outputting the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining query within your loop? If so it will be unset as soon as you exit the loop. In order to fix this define it as null before the loop sets and it should work.

```
$query = "";
loop{
    ...
}
echo  "<a href=mass_qty_update.php?".rtrim($query,'&')."><button>"."Update All Quantities"."</button></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you are looking for:

```
$i=0;

$link = 'mass_qty_update.php?';
$chunks = array();

while($i<5){
    $i++;  
    $chunks[] = 'id_'.$i.'='.$i;
}

$link .= implode('&', $chunks);

echo $link;

// Output: mass_qty_update.php?id_1=1&id_2=2&id_3=3&id_4=4&id_5=5
```

Look at how implode was used and how array is created.